# redisson can't work in spring boot 3.0.0-M5 or RC1

Tags: spring-boot

my dependencies:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.0.0-RC1'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.0.0-RC1'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis:3.0.0-RC1'
implementation 'org.redisson:redisson-spring-boot-starter:3.17.7'
```

my error:

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in jp.co.netstars.boss.core.api.aspect.RateLimitAspect required a bean of type 'org.redisson.api.RedissonClient' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.redisson.api.RedissonClient' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

it works fine with version 3.0.0-M4.but not in RC1

Comment: https://github.com/redisson/redisson/blob/master/redisson-spring-boot-starter/README.md They provide support up to 2.7.x version not 3.0.x spring boot version

Comment: but it works fine with 3.0.0-M4